How to list disconnected nodes from VertexDelete
In the following example, nodes N1 and N9 become disconnected (lose all links) when the following code is run:
edges = {N1 -> x, x -> N3, x -> x, N4 -> N5, N6 -> N2, N6 -> N3, 
   N6 -> N4, N1 -> N8, N2 -> N8, N4 -> N8, N7 -> N8, N9 -> N7, 
   N9 -> N8};
g = Graph[edges, VertexLabels -> Automatic]
gg = VertexDelete[g, x | N7 | N8]
EdgeList[gg] // TableForm

Shown from the graphs produced by this code, I would like to generate two lists. List 1 is a list of nodes that remain after vertex delete. List 2 is a list of nodes that no longer have any links (incoming or outgoing, they become isolated).
In the above code List 1 = {N2, N3, N4, N5, N6}, List 2 = {N1, N9}. Any help is most appreciated!

We can GatherBy the vertices based on if their VertexDegree is 0 (note the vertices with degree 0 come first in this case):
GatherBy[VertexList[gg], VertexDegree[gg, #] == 0 &]

(*{{N1, N9}, {N3, N4, N5, N6, N2}}*)


wonderful ... thank u for sharing your code! ...

not sure why {N1, N9} comes first, is it becomes GatherBy place the smaller list first and the longer list next, and so forth?

GatherBy follows the ordering of the supplied list, so it's just because N1 is the first element of VertexList[gg]. If we change the ordering so N1 or N9 is not the first element of the vertex list, the other group will come first:
$$ $$
SeedRandom[2];
$$ $$
randOrd = RandomSample[VertexList@gg, VertexCount@gg]
$$ $$
(*{N2, N3, N4, N9, N5, N6, N1}*)
$$ $$
GatherBy[randOrd, VertexDegree[gg, #] == 0 &]
$$ $$
{{N2, N3, N4, N5, N6}, {N9, N1}}
$$ $$

makes sense ... many thanks!
